# OAUTH - Implement authorization_code workflow

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented the oauth workflow to get access and refresh tokens. Custom classes for OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and AuthenticationTokenProvider are in place and working.

I'm trying to add Single Sign On functionality (to provide access to third parties through our system), but I'm not sure how it should be done or if I'm missing some pieces.

This is the workflow I would like to implement:

1. Third party calls /api/Account/ExternalLogin
2. User gets a login page where they enter the credentials
3. User is validated through /token call (as if they were trying to get access token)
4. Third party calls /token with the authorization_code to get the access_token

I'm missing something between step 3 and 4. When you validate a user, you get an access_token but you should redirect the user to 3rd party url with authorization_code so 3rd party system can get the access_token. That's what I do not get.

Comment: this isn't very clear, who exactly is doing the user authorization in your scenario?

Comment: We provide login feature to a 3rd party (Client). Their users will be authenticated on our system. Once we authorize their users in our system, we want to send the authorization_code to the Client

Answer (score 0):

ok so the workflow is like this ( if I remember correctly! ):

The client will need some sort of setup on your side because you need to know to which URL to send the authorization code.

The user goes to your authorization page and inputs their username / password. If everything checks out, you issue an authorization code and redirect the user back to their URL, passing the code in the URL.

This client URL can look like this:  `https://www.client.co.uk/authcode_endpoint?code=blah`

At this point your job is done for now.

Next, the client will receive this code on their system ( because you called their URL) and can now issue another call to you, to exchange the code for a token and the process repeats.

You send them back to another URL : `https://www.client.co.uk/authtoken_endpoint?token=blah`

Now they can issue more calls to do what they need to do.

Something like this should be fairly straightforward to do, you have an app to app communication basically. There must be libraries that already provide this kind of workflow for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The problem I have is that I authorize the user on grant_type=password, so the token and Ticket are generated in the RefreshTokenProvider class. When I call to exchange the code for an access token (grant_type=authorize_code), I need to deserialize the ticket in the AuthorizationCodeProvider class. As far as I know, the ticket can only be deserialize on the same provider that has been serialized. That's the piece I'm missing